# The Node JS FS Code which works perfectly on Windows Doesn't work in an Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, filesystems

the following Code Works Perfectly on My Machine, However When I put it online on an Ubuntu server, it seems it has some problems. I'm not sure why

```js
if (!existsSync(`${some path}/${MemberID}`)){
    mkdirSync(`${some path}/${MemberID}`);
}
```

I think It has something to do with different file systems in Windows and Linux. 
I'm not even a Linux Beginner. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you don't have permissions to create directory

Use `ls -l` for check permissions

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that path of ${some path} already exist.

Second, check that the access rights for the running node process has permissions to create that pathes.

Third, try on terminal / console (replace some path and MemberID with real path and value)

```sh
mkdir "some path/MemberID"
```